# Illegal seek when aws-sdk S3 download calls #rewind on IO.pipe writer

Tags: ruby, pipe, aws-sdk

Consider the following function. It operates on a large CSV file downloaded from AWS S3 without consuming unnecessary memory or disk. Ruby is 2.3.1, aws-sdk is 2.6.12.

```
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'csv'

def s3_reader(region, bucket, file)
  bucket = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: region).bucket(bucket)
  reader, writer = IO.pipe
  t = Thread.new do
    bucket.object(file).get(response_target: writer)
    writer.close
  end
  t.abort_on_exception = true

  CSV.new(reader, headers: true).each_with_index do |_, n|
    print '.' if (n % 1000).zero?
  end
end
```

Problem is, when the S3 Ruby API is done, it wants to be helpful and rewind the IO object it received. This explodes thus:

```
./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.6.12/lib/seahorse/client/http/response.rb:103:in `rewind': Illegal seek (Errno::ESPIPE)
from ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.6.12/lib/seahorse/client/http/response.rb:103:in `signal_done'
from ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.6.12/lib/seahorse/client/http/response.rb:116:in `signal_error'
from ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.6.12/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/handler.rb:90:in `rescue in transmit'
from ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.6.12/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/handler.rb:68:in `transmit'
from ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.6.12/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/handler.rb:42:in `call'
```

The only way I can see to work around this is to simply:

```
  writer.instance_eval('undef :rewind')
```

Which qualifies as one of the uglier workarounds I have done.

Am I missing something here? Is there a reasonable way to avoid this problem? (I'm not seeing any in the aws-sdk source)?

Alternatively, should a) Ruby's IO.pipe not expose a #rewind and/or b) aws-sdk not assume that just because #rewind exists, it should not expect to be able to call it?

Comment: It inherits `rewind` from IO but I don't think you can rewind a pipe

Comment: So in some sense the AWS Ruby API is wrong in assuming that rewind can be called on any IO object, given that a pipe is one of the more likely response_target:s (files and memory being handled by simpler methods)? I suppose you can't rewind a BSD socket or a filesystem pipe either and those would be "proper" IO objects.

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/1324